# Microsoft Graph API getting groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using microsoft graph api to access groups in azure active directory, I have created 2 groups in AAD named OIC and other named as testing

[image]

When I test using microsoft graph explorer, URL that I use

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "value": []
}
```

Why do I get empty value for groups even though I have groups in AAD.

I have logged in as admin user.
[image]

Comment: Please let us know Whether you are able to get the data using PowerShell Get-AzureADGroup

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your graph API while running in  explorer and please follow the guideline given this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for posting for the screenshot. I created newly created groups, tested with Graph explorer and it works for me. can you please provide logs/timestamp of your graph logs and also please check in the  postman

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have created groups in a tenant which is not your home tenant.

*It means credentials are only owned by a single tenant. The tenant is discovered by Graph Explorer based on domain. You cannot use Graph Explorer to query tenants your account is a guest on, it can only query the tenant that owns the account. It retrieves data from the tenant you (or your app) authenticated against. It cannot query across multiple tenants.*

The only way to use those creds with another tenant would be to force the OAuth uri to use that tenants ID instead of `common`. This isn't supported by Explorer. You'd have to download the source an reengineer the auth process.

**Reference SO thread:** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341544/how-can-i-change-default-tenant-in-microsoft-graph-explorer#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20sign,use%20tenant%20query%20string%20parameter.&text=A%20simple%20url%20to%20go,or%20tenantId%2C%20both%20work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341544/how-can-i-change-default-tenant-in-microsoft-graph-explorer#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20sign,use%20tenant%20query%20string%20parameter.&text=A%20simple%20url%20to%20go,or%20tenantId%2C%20both%20work)).